# Justify text using Pillow / Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow 7.2.0 in Python 3 to insert text into an image with a fixed size.

I now want to insert text with a fixed font and font size into a specific width and have it justified, like a fixed text-box. The text should be justified within the text-box so it touches the left and right end. I don't see any documentation for how to do this.

What is the most reasonable method to do this?

I do want for it to be able to squish the text horizontally to fit the text-box without creating a second line, although it is seldom the case.

As a sidenote I was looking through the documentation for Pillow and was wondering what the anchor parameter does. I didn't find any explanation for it.

```
ImageDraw.text(... anchor=None, ...)
```

Comment: The anchor parameter was ignored until Pillow 8.0.0. It is now used to specify how the `xy` parameter should be aligned to text. The documentation is here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pillow does not have a built-in way to justify text. The best way to justify text is to break it by spaces and insert spaces to fill the remaining space.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 20)
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n"\
       "Pellentesque accumsan nec felis ut vulputate."

image_width = 600
im = Image.new("RGB", (image_width, 80), "white")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

y = 10
for line in text.split("\n"):
    words = line.split(" ")
    words_length = sum(d.textlength(w, font=font) for w in words)
    space_length = (image_width - words_length) / (len(words) - 1)
    x = 0
    for word in words:
        d.text((x, y), word, font=font, fill="black")
        x += d.textlength(word, font=font) + space_length
    y += 30
```

[image: example of justified text]

Comment: Can you please edit this coding part for getting output in Text Widget (not as an image) ?

Comment: @sonny Text Widget? OP's question is about Pillow, a library for dealing with images, not widgets... You probably want to search for an answer involving your GUI framework, not Pillow.

Comment: yes sir. I tried to justify some text content on text widget. can you help me sir ?

Comment: @sonny No, I have no idea what framework you are using to create your "text widget". Please open a new question with the necessary detail. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76893172/how-to-text-justify-in-python?noredirect=1#comment135560526_76893172